# How to make the input not automatically execute when I paste in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, copy-paste

I have a feeling that this is a very simple fix, but whenever I try to paste into PowerShell using right-click, it automatically executes whatever it is I am trying to paste. The function is finding a computer name based on an input using AD and then copies the computer name to use in other functions. Here is the code for only the part that does the copying:

```
    $strComputer = $output.Name
    $strComputer | clip | Out-Null
```

So when I right-click to paste, it executes whatever $strComputer equals and obviously throws an error. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the error? What is the clip command doing? I just tried this locally (though I don't have access to AD here so not a complete test) and I cannot reproduce what you are saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with pasting something into PowerShell (and `clip.exe` is very good example) is the fact, that any newline (and `clip.exe` used like that will add newline at the end) will trigger same reaction that you pressing enter would.

There are at least two ways around it:

- paste without newlines (e.g. use `[System.Windows.Clipboard]::SetText($output.Name)`)
- if you are on v3 - use [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) module and CTRL+V

For the first one - be sure to run `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore` first - this assembly is loaded by default only in PowerShell ISE. If you are on v3+ though I would really recommend to give PSReadLine a try.

Comment: And if you are using PSCX you can use `$strComputer | Set-Clipboard` as opposed to `Out-Clipboard` which appends the newline.

Answer (score 3):

I've found an easy solution, that doesn't require any Powershell modifications.

Steps:

1. Type `if ($true) {` into the terminal.
2. Paste in the code-block. Because you started an if-block, but didn't provide an end-bracket for it, Powershell interprets the code-block as incomplete, and so awaits the end-bracket before running anything.
3. Now you can use the arrow keys to edit the code block however you want.
4. When you're done with your edits, add the missing `}` to the very end, then press enter to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the ISE, where you can paste into the Script Pane (the top half), and edit until it appears as desired, and run when you want to.